# std::chrono::floor добавляет 3 часа

Tags: c++, std-chrono

```
using TimePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point;
TimePoint curTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
// Здесь время: 2021-03-02 13:37:31.122

using days = std::chrono::duration
        <int, std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<(24 * 60 * 60)>, std::chrono::seconds::period>>;

curTime = std::chrono::floor<days>(curTime);
// Здесь время: 2021-03-02 03:00:00.000
```

Почему округление вниз происходит до +3 часа а не до нуля 2021-03-02 00:00:00.000 ?
Предполагаю, что вмешивается часовой пояс.
Каким образом округлить до нуля вне зависимости от часового пояса?

Ничего лучше не придумал, чем обнулить через структуру std::tm

```
auto timeT = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(curTime);
std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&timeT);
tm.tm_min = 0;
tm.tm_sec = 0;
tm.tm_hour = 0;
curTime = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&tm));
```

Answer (score 3):

Да, виноват часовой пояс. Нет, часовой пояс в округлении не участвует.

Тип `time_point` не хранит часовой пояс. Стандарт не указывает какое время там должно быть. Обычно это время по Гринвичу или GMT или UTC или Unix time.

Когда вы вызываете `floor` - время округляется по Гринвичу.

До сих пор часовой пояс никак не участвовал в процессе. Вы задействуете его когда вызываете `std::localtime`, который переводит гринвичское время в московское (вы ведь в Москве?) и добавляет три часа: когда в Гринвиче полночь, в Москве три часа ночи.

И так `time_point` не поддерживает часовые пояса, а вы хотите округлять время с участием текущего часового пояса, в Москве. Раз так, то решение предложенное вами правильное - вы перевели время из Гринвича в Москву и затем округлили.